# Cannot open ini file `omnetpp.ini'

Tags: ini, omnet++

I'm a graduate student in computer networking and researching Content-Centric networks and going to use a ccnSim simulator.

I am an amateur in OMNeT++.

ccnSim is written in C++ under the OMNeT++ framework.

I have installed ccnSim in OMNeT++ but have got problem.
I've got error Cannot open ini file omnetpp.ini.

I would be really appreciated if you could help me by a Comprehensive guide.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Which simulation are you trying to start? Is it launched with the correct working directory, where the `omnetpp.ini` file is located?

Comment: I want to use the ccnSim simulator but it uses the omnet ++ framework to run. I have created the executable file for this simulator but when the executable file runs or when  i enter ./ccnSim  in mingwenv.cmd to run ,The error message is displayed. I don't know how to import such files into the omnet ++ graphical environment, and many times when I imported this package through the file menu, the program displays "make" not found in PATH, which is a C / C ++ Problem error or errors appear as a "NED Consistency problem"

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your omnetpp.ini and *.ned files to the same directory as your compiled executable or change your working directory to your "simulation" directory.